# How to catch TCP socket transmission failures in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, networking, tcp

When I write data to a TCP socket in Node, which is not closed but the client on the other side is not connected anymore (because of network failure for example), how do I know?

The socket's error event doesn't fire in this case for me. If I'm right, TCP gives up sending data, if there is absolutely no ACK packets from the other side, doesn't it? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [Nodejs Net documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket).
Socket events are `close`, `connect`, `data`, `drain`, `end`, `error`, `lookup`, and `timeout`.

Since you're not getting an `error` event, try listening to the `end` event which is emitted when the other end of the socket sends a `FIN` packet.

```
socket.on('end', () => console.log('socket has ended'))
```

Alternatively, if you expect a network failure or other unpredictable network edge cases on their end; you can always set a timeout and handle it that way.

```
socket.setTimeout(60000) // 60 seconds
socket.on('timeout', () => {
  console.warn('socket has timed out')
  socket.write('socket has timed out')
  socket.end()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[`close` event](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_close_1) listeners are passed a `hadError` arg that indicates if the socket was closed because of a transmission error.  For example:

```
socket.on('close', hadError => {
  if (hadError) {
    // Handle transmission error here
  }
});
```